# DateTime already installed from cpan and cpanm but still cant locate in @INC

Tags: perl

How is possible to not locate DateTime.pm even though I have installed it from cpan and cpanm? But still get the error it cannot find it in @INC? It is not duplicate because I don ask about who to donwload modul - as I said I tried to install it from 2 sources and i did, but still the error `Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC`. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

the code is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime;
my $t = localtime;
my $now = DateTime->new(
year => $t->year,
month => $t->mon,
day => $t->mday,
);
print $now
```

and error:

```
Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DateTime module) (@INC contains:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28
    /usr/share/perl/5.28
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
) at ./a line 2.
```

Seems i cant find DateTime.pm but I do have them here:

```
/home/shepherd/.cpan/build/DateTime-1.51-0/blib/lib/DateTime.pm
/home/shepherd/.cpan/build/DateTime-1.51-0/lib/DateTime.pm
/home/shepherd/.cpan/build/DateTime-TimeZone-2.37-0/t/lib/T/RequireDateTime.pm
/home/shepherd/.cpanm/work/1572257193.20577/DateTime-1.51/lib/DateTime.pm
/home/shepherd/.cpanm/work/1572257193.20577/DateTime-TimeZone-2.37/t/lib/T/RequireDateTime.pm
/home/shepherd/.cpanm/work/1572257544.21848/DateTime-1.51/lib/DateTime.pm
/home/shepherd/.cpanm/work/1572257544.21848/DateTime-TimeZone-2.37/t/lib/T/RequireDateTime.pm
```

What the hell is going on?

---

Some information that might be useful:

```
$ which cpan
/usr/bin/cpan

$ head -n 1 `which cpan`
usr/bin/perl

$ which cpanm
/usr/bin/cpanm

$ head -n 1 `which cpanm`
usr/bin/perl

$ /usr/bin/perl -V:'inst.*lib'
installarchlib='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28';
installprivlib='/usr/share/perl/5.28'
installsitelib='/usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1'
installvendorlib='/usr/share/perl5'

@INC (when 'use DateTime;')
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28
/usr/share/perl/5.28
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

the command `set | grep ^PERL` echoes nothing, i've tried `set | grep -i perl` but just was mentioned in some if statements, like this: `if type perl &> /dev/null; then`. And the second command `echo 'o conf' | cpan` is this: `Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 2023). Contacting... Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile '/home/shepherd/.cpan/.lock'? (Y/n) [y] Ok, bye`

Comment: Can you include your code in your question? The issue might potentially lie there.

Comment: The full error message should display the contents of INC. is DateTime.pm in one of those directories? Does the process running your script have read access to that pm file and search permissions on all the directories in INC before and including that directory?

Comment: No, i indeed cannot find it. But I do have it in other strange dirs, that the CPAN and CPANM did it for me. (Those dirs were made when installing from command prompt), but I supposed the should work as well?

Comment: You either have more than one build of Perl (installing for one and then trying to use another one), or the installer was instructed to install the module in a non-standard location and `perl` wasn't told to look there. What's the output of `set | grep ^PERL; which cpan; head -n 1 \`which cpan\`; which cpanm; head -n 1 \`which cpanm\`; echo 'o conf' | cpan`

Comment: `which cpan` = /usr/bin/cpan     `head -n  1 \`which cpan\`` = usr/bin/perl     `which cpanm` = /usr/bin/cpanm     `head -n 1 \`which cpanm\`` = usr/bin/perl.            Still dont get it

Comment: 1) You need to use `@ikegami` if you want me to be notified. 2) You should be providing that information in you question. (Fixed) 3) Pretty sure that isn't the output you actually got from two of those commands. 4) You left out the output of the most important commands! Please provide the requested information 5) Provide the output of `/usr/bin/perl -V:'inst.*lib'` too

Comment: @ikegami why is the config vars of inst* needed? There they are:          `installarchlib='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28';`
`installprivlib='/usr/share/perl/5.28';`
`installsitelib='/usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1';`
`installvendorlib='/usr/share/perl5';`

Comment: Still waiting on the outputs of `set | grep ^PERL` and `echo 'o conf' | cpan`. /// If you don't override the installation location, we'll need to check the permissions of the default installation location.

Comment: @ikegami the command  `set | grep  ^PERL` echoes nothing, i've tried `set | grep -i perl` but just was mentioned in some if statements, like this: `if type perl &> /dev/null; then`. And the second command `echo 'o conf' | cpan` is this: `Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 2023).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile '/home/shepherd/.cpan/.lock'? (Y/n) [y] Ok, bye`

Comment: It would be far easier to follow this if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58589831/edit) and add all of this information there.

Comment: @DaveCross sorry, it is updated now.

Comment: `cpan` didn't properly exit last time. Could you launch `cpan`, say yes to overwriting the lock file, exit (`quit`), and run the command again?

Comment: `set | grep ^PERL` echoing nothing is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The directories where you can see `DateTime` (under `/home/shepherd/.cpan`) are working directories that `cpan` and `cpanm` use when installing your modules. You wouldn't expect to actually load modules from there once they have been installed - as other copies of the modules should be installed somewhere more permanent.

But where have they been installed? That's the question. By default, they should be installed somewhere on your default `@INC` path, but they're clearly not there - otherwise you wouldn't get that error message.

So I'm led to suspect that either there was an error when installing the modules or they somehow got installed in a non-standard place on your system. And it's impossible to give much more useful help without seeing exactly what commands you ran to install the modules and what output was produced.

Comment: ok, here are all commands I've tried: `sudo apt-get install libdatetime-perl` `cpan DateTime` `cpanm DateTime`. And As saw the output, lot of dependecies missing, but I suppose these commands `cpan DateTime` should establish those dependencies for me, otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: Similarly i found other question here, that seems to be similar to my question: https://serverfault.com/questions/54297/cpan-fails-to-install-datetime-module?newreg=34b4170617c94546872f8853f11f8b35   -- but that is server error

Comment: @Herdsman: Any one of those commands should have worked. The first one would be the one I would use. But without seeing the output, it's impossible to be any more help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've had the same problem. Many times. When you `sudo apt-get install libsomething-perl` the DateTime.pm file, or one of the directories it resides under, might not be readable to your normal user. (Depending on `umask` or `g+s` settings I think)

To check this out, see if it's available as root (sudo) and where it's located by running:

```
sudo perl -le'use DateTime; print $INC{"DateTime.pm"}'
```

Then run:

```
sudo ls -ld $(sudo perl -E'use DateTime;@p=split"/",$INC{"DateTime.pm"};say join"/",@p and pop@p while@p>1')
```

And you might see something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root root   4096 Aug 30  2016 /usr
drwxr-xr-x  root root  12288 Oct  9 10:22 /usr/lib
drwxr-xr-x  root root  69632 Oct 23 06:35 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
drwxr-xr-x  root root   4096 Aug 30  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5
drwxr-xr-x  root root   4096 Oct  9 10:22 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux- gnu/perl5/5.22
-rw-r--r--  root root 123586 Dec 18  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/DateTime.pm
```

If your current user don't have the permissions needed to read the DateTime.pm file or a directory it's in, try using either `sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/` or `sudo chmod a+rx /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/DateTime.pm` or similar to change that. (The directories in my examples here should of course be changed into what you got from the `ls` command above)

Comment: Yes I got the same output and yes I do have my permissions. But dont get the point, even if I did what you said